# How do i get google doc name from url in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

[image of my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zOyO.png)

This is my sheet image

I tried to search but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From your following sample spreadsheet (this image is from your question.),

  [image]
- You want to retrieve the URLs of Google Document files from the cells "B3:B", and you want to retrieve the document titles and want to put the document titles in the column "A".

In this case, how about the following sample script? Unfortunately, in the current stage, your goal cannot be achieved by the built-in functions. So, in this answer, Google Apps Script is used.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set your sheet name to `sheetName` and save the script. And, please run `myFunction` with the script editor. And, please authorize the scopes. By this, the script is run. When this script is run, the google document URLs are retrieved from "B3:B" and converted the URLs to the document titles, and the titles are put into the column "A".

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("B3:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(([url]) => [url ? DocumentApp.openByUrl(url).getName() : null]);
  range.offset(0, -1).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this script, your provided sample Spreadsheet is used. When you change your Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.
- In this script, it supposes that all URLs of "B3:B" are the URLs of Google Documents. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [openByUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openbyurlurl)
- [getName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getName())